# Mail Server DNS configuration of MX Records for Forwarding

Tags: email, dns, exchange-server, sendmail

I have an account with an internet provider, the majority of my company is based on the mail server they provide which is a bog standard UX style server from what I can tell. They offer the ability to edit the DNS records in the admin login, and you can edit the MX records.

What I want to do is introduce a subset of email accounts that are managed by a second mail server, this being an MS Exchange server. So what I want, I think, is to configure the Authoritative server as the 1and1 server, and configure the Exchange server as a non-Authoritative server and have the Authoritative server forward all non local addresses, or specified addresses, on to the Exchange server. Thus all addresses would look the same old_mx@ab.com and exchange@ab.com, but they would be resolved by different mail servers, working in tandem. My assumption had been you could specify a destination for unresolved e-mail addresses before they are declared void and bounced.

I spoke to a support engineer at 1and1 who said it was possible but they needed the exchange server address. Seemed reasonable, MS seem to think it's possible and provided an address. I just phoned the ISP back with the Exchange server details as provided by MS...  and the next engineer says it isn't possible.

Can we confirm this is possible firstly, and how would I go about configuring it?

Answer (score 0):

Not much help has been forthcoming on this question, but I do have some leads on answers myself. It would seem that there is no DNS record solution to the problem, not one commonly supported anyway. The DNS can only really be used for primary and secondary MX definition.

The only way to set this form of triaged MX server seems to rely on the MS Exchange server being defined as the first link in a chain of mail servers. i.e. The DNS referenced server. Once this is done the MS Exchange server can be configured as a non-Authoritative reference, within the server. Once that is done the MS Exchange is then provided with the subsequent servers to reference. On receipt of an e-mail that the MSE server doesn't recognise it will then forward the mail to another server that might be another non-authoritative MSE or an authoritative server of any description. The end server would then be responsible for returning any error messages back to the sender.

If anyone finds a better solution that doesn't involve redefining the master mail MX records I would be very interested, as I don't really want the MSE setup as the primary MX record.